# Setting collection view methods only after Firebase call is complete

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm attempting to set the `numberOfItemsInSection` method of my collection view with the `count` of a certain dictionary. The dictionary is set from a Firebase call (code below if that part matters). I was under the impression that Firebase calls were asynchronous anyway, and wouldn't need to be combined with a dispatch queue, closure, or separate completion handler.

However, when I try to set `numberOfItemsInSection` to `return avatarDictionary.count`, it's empty, and indeed printing that count shows 0. The dictionary in question does get set with its values (printing confirms that), but it needs to loop through all the users I'm fetching data for before it has all its values. I think when `numberOfItemsInSection` checks its `return`, the dictionary is still at 0.

Is that what's happening? If so, what's the best way to make sure the dictionary is fully set with all its values before setting the collection view?

Code:

```
func getParticipantInfo() {

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    // Query Firebase users with those UIDs & grab their gender, profilePicture, and name
    databaseRef.child("groups").child(currentRoomID).child("participants").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

            for each in snapDict {

                let uid  = each.key
                let avatar = each.value["profilePicture"] as! String
                let gender = each.value["gender"] as! String
                let handle = each.value["handle"] as! String
                let name = each.value["name"] as! String

                // Set those to the dictionaries [UID : value]
                self.avatarDictionary.setValue(avatar, forKey: uid)
                self.nameDictionary.setValue(name, forKey: uid)
                self.genderDictionary.setValue(gender, forKey: uid)
                self.handleDictionary.setValue(handle, forKey: uid)
                print("\n\navatarDictionary:\n \(self.avatarDictionary)")
                print("\nhandleDictionary:\n \(self.handleDictionary)")
                print("\ngenderDictionary:\n \(self.genderDictionary)")
                print("\nnameDictionary:\n \(self.nameDictionary)")
            }
        }
    }, withCancel: {(Err) in
        print(Err.localizedDescription)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this after setting the array

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

(Right after the for loop)

Comment: Somehow I always forget the reload. Thanks!